# I can't see the shapefile

Tags: shapefile, ecognition

I'm going to analyze a shapefile using drone photos and cadastral maps.

I tried to load both data into Ecognition with the same coordinate system, but the cadastral map shapefile is not shown.

Why can't I see the shapefile?

[image]

[image]

Comment: So the good news is that this is the most common question asked in GIS SE, even if you don't count all the different software stacks with slightly different solutions. The bad news is that your data *isn't* in the same spatial reference, even if someone convinced the software that it was, so you're going to need to [Edit] the Question to provide spatial reference details, including the definition and the coordinate extent of each of the layers.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! It looks like you have a coordinate system problem, see if any of the suggestions at https://ihatecoordinatesystems.com/ help.

Comment: Thanks eveybody. The coordinate system was aligned with EPGS5186. I think the shp file is a problem rather than a coordinate system problem, but it doesn't appear anywhere even if you upload the shp file to ecognition and zoom it. Is there a way to save the shp file or a property value that needs to be set?